# Cant import pygame

Tags: python, visual-studio, pygame

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'pygame'
```

in vscode, I tried the terminal in vs using `python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens`

it worked but I tried importing from file but said not module

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
pip install pygame
```

or try:

```
pip3 install pygame
```

or maybe:

```
python -m pip install pygame
```

For details go to official website of pygame:
https://pypi.org/project/pygame/

In python bash try to import after installation process is done.
It verifies the installation. If it works in python bash it will definitely work in code.

Comment: pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install pygame
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundExcep  
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: try pip3 install pygame or python3 -m pip3 install pygame. maybe some problem in your $PATH. you need to set that..